# Using fixtures inside setup_module and teardown_module

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a few setup tasks that needs to be done before all the tests get executed and after that needs to be executed.
Since, there is an fixture that does the setting up, I kind of want to do it by passing a fixture as an argument.

```
table_name = 'table_name_1'
# database and mock_data are fixtures defined in conftest.py
def setup_module(database, mock_data):
    database.insert_data(table_name, mock_json_data)


def test_1():
    // some test


def teardown_module(database):
    database.delete_data(table_name)
```

Comment: You can rewrite `setup_module`/`teardown_module` to autouse fixtures with module scope.

Comment: Is there an example you could point to ?

Comment: Kindly, give the expected output along with the question, so that it would be helpful to debug more.

Comment: Rename `setup_module` to e.g. `my_setup_fixture` and decorate it with e.g. `@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='module')`. If you need more examples, check out [pytest fixtures: explicit, modular, scalable](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html).